# Bean validation on managed entity

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

On a rest ubdate request , first i am reading related object from database ,second mapping dto to just readed dbObject using dozer  framework standart mapper,DozerBeanMapper . Next i am trying to validate new mapped object but validation fail because of  one field annotated with 
**`@NotEmpty(message = "Name cannot be empty ")`**  is seems null ,i know this occurs because dbObject is a dynamic proxy object  refering my entity  handled by hibernate ,is there any way  validating  managed bean annotated with hibernate.validator.constaints  using hibernate validator .

```
@PUT
public Response update(QueryDTO dto) throws   ServiceException {
    log.info("Request for upadating   query");

     Query dbObject= this.persistenceService.find( Query.class,dto.getSystemId());
     if(dbObject.getVersion()!=dto.getVersion()){
          throw new InvalidVersionException("Db version is" + dbObject.getVersion());
     }
    this.mapper.map(dto,dbObject);


    Set<ConstraintViolation<Query>>  validationResult= this.validator.validate(dbObject);
    if(!validationResult.isEmpty()){
        throw new ValidationException(StringifyUtil.buildExceptionMessage(validationResult));
    }

    Query updatedObject=   this.persistenceService.update(dbObject);
    return ok(updatedObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the BeanValidation API a TraversableResolver is used to check if a property is reachable by the validator. Depending on the hibernate validator version you are using there are implementations for Hibernate/JPA addressing this problem.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/TraversableResolver.html
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/resolver/package-summary.html

You can configure a TraversableResolver this way

```
    final Configuration<?> conf = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure();
    conf.traversableResolver(new MyTraversableResolver());
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = conf.buildValidatorFactory();
```

see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bootstrapping.html#d0e4238 for bootstrapping the validator